# Spherical functions for sl(2,Q_p)

Tags: harmonic-analysis, unitary-representations, p-adic-groups

I kindly would like to ask you the following- I am refering to page
175 in the Book by Gelfand, Graev, Shapiro, etc, on "Automorphic forms
..."

My question to which I would kindly ask you to answer me is : Are
there unitary representations of SL(2, Q_P) of type I (that is with
spherical functions) that are not in the continuous series. Gelfand is
ambiguous in the text by saying that he will give examples of such
class 1 unitary representations in the continuous series. If there
other type I  unitary reps, in which series are they (the discrete
series perhaps?).

What would be the trace formula for this class 1, non-principal series?

Comment: Being type I and having spherical functions are different things. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry by class I, I meant spherical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful that among the irreducible unitary reps also the trivial representation has this property. That's why Paul Garrett says "embeds" into a prinicpal series, so you get not only unramified unitary principal series, but also the trivial representations.

Paul Garrett doesn't address the trace formula, so I will try to do this:

Let $F$ be a local field, $B$ the Borel in $SL(2)$, and $K$ being a maximal compact subgroup of $SL(2,F)$ with $SL(2,F) = B(F) \cdot K$.

Let $\mu$ be a complex character and $\pi(\mu) = Ind_{B(F)}^{SL(2,F)} \mu$ be the normalized induction (=principal series), then
$$ tr\; \pi(\mu) (\phi) = \int\limits_{B(F)} \int_K \phi(k^{-1}bk) \mu(b) \Delta(b)^{1/2}\; dk \; db,$$
where the right Haar measures are related as
$$ \int_G d g = \int_B \int_K dkdb.$$
In your case, you could take $\phi$ being right and left $K$-invariant, hence can replace the $K$-integral by $vol(K)$. So yes, there is a strong analogy between p-adic and Lie groups.

Comment: Thks a lot for answs. Still very puzzled if a spherical representation for SL(2,Q_p)  in the  non-principal series, has an associated character. Does the procedure which gives the character for a spherical in the principal series, diverge for representations not in the left regular. The procedure, would compute the "trace at g" by taking the trace of images of convolutors by characteristic functions of sets A, containing g, normalizing by Haar measure of A, and then taking the limit when A shrinks to g. Does this procedure diverge for non principal, since they are not in the Planch. series?

Comment: Being in the left regular correspond to being tempered, so you will not get the trivial representation nor the non-tempered principal series. But it does not matter, my computation assume $\mu$ general, not necessarily unitary. You probably means character seen as a function, which is locally integrable - not as a distribution. Yes you can do a similiar things whether as long as you assume admissible.

Comment: But are these characters for non-principal, complementary unitary spherical being computed (even as distribution)?- It is my impression that either in Sally, either Gelfand do not make the computation

Comment: I gave the formula for the distribution. It is general. If you want to find a function on $G$ corresponding to this, I can't tell where to look for explicit computations. My feeling is that finding some useful computational analogy can only done to some extent. $P$-adic Gamma factors do not look like real or complex Gamma-functions.

Answer (score 4):

The theorem of Borel-Casselman-Matsumoto from about 1976 shows, more generally, that any admissible representation of a $p$-adic reductive group with an Iwahori-fixed vector imbeds in an unramified principal series. In particular, an admissible representation with a spherical vector is in this class, that is, is a subrepresentation (and quotient) of an unramified principal series.

Comment: Does this imply that every  unitary spherical representation is continuously occurring in the left regular representation of p-adic group?

Comment: Yes... while noting that proving admissibility of (irreducible) unitaries of p-adic reductive groups is non-trivial. (Harish-Chandra and others reduced to the supercuspidal case, finished by Bernstein c. 1975.)

Comment: So this also implies discrete (square integrable) unitary series contains no spherical? If this is true, I can not imagine how the discrete series then occurs in the L^2 space of the left regular representation of G?

Comment: Correct, discrete series do not have spherical vectors. Also, I'd say it is correct that it is non-trivial to see how discrete series occur in $L^2(G)$ or $L^2(G/Z)$, indeed. For $SL_2$, pairing with $O(1,1)$ (in effect) and Segal-Shale-Weil/oscillator constructs _some_ of these. In effect, this is what is done in Gelfand-et-al, though I don't remember whether they really convincingly prove exhaustion.

Comment: I think they prove exhaustation by Plancherel formula. Are there,  in the p-adic SL2, any characters of unitary irreducibles that may bear a resemblance to the characters in the discrete series of SL(2,R)?

Comment: I've not carried out the computation myself, but I'd strongly expect that the discrete series repns produced from local oscillator repns for $SL(2)$ would admit essentially identical trace computations, via that presentation of them.

Comment: I think the right question to ask is: Do the spherical representations in what Gelfand calls supplementary series have a trace formula? What are their characters?

Comment: By analytic continuation, the characters of the "unitary" principal series will give the characters of _all_ principal series, regardless of unitarizability, etc.